# Access Denied when enable Publishing Feature for a Site Collection

Tags: feature

When I enable "Sharepoint Publishing Feature" for a Site-Collection I get Access Denied. I tried using the Farm Administrator and the Site-Collection Administrator to access the site.

I tried activating it through Powershell and from the site.

I can supply you with logs if you want.

Anyone

Comment: Yes it would be good to see some of the log details.

Comment: Have you got a custom branding solution? Is "NT Authority\All Authenticated Users" added to the "Style Rescource Readers" group?

Comment: Hey, my Central Administration gor a custom branding but not that webapplication/sitecollection.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, the wierdest thing happend.

I gave "Style Rescource Readers" Full Control. Does anyone wanna explain what the group does and why?

Comment: Check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92862/style-resource-readers-allow-access-to-list-views